# Error on Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the query I tried to execute and got the error.  Here is the original error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 36 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

As user1@abc.com I want to see all the records that people reporting to me directly and records of those that report to people under me directly. Base on the data I want to see EmployeeID 273, 16, 274, 285, 286, 275, 276, 23.

The goal to get all the records that >= to 
user1@abc.com  **Level**.  Here is the current data in the table look like. [image: TOrganization_Hierarchy]

```
select A.ManagerID, A.ManagerEmail, A.Email, A.EmployeeID, A.Title, A.DeptID, A.Level
from TOrganization_Hierarchy A
where  A.ManagerEmail = 'user1@abc.com'
and A.Level >= (select B.Level
            from TOrganization_Hierarchy B
            where  B.ManagerEmail = A.ManagerEmail) ;
```

**HI ALL, I HAVE FIGURED IT OUT, below is the code that ran**

```
WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT OH.employeeid, 
                OH.managerid, 
                OH.email AS EMPEMAIL, 
                1        AS level 
         FROM   TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY OH 
         WHERE  OH.[email] = user1@abc.com
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT CHIL.employeeid, 
                CHIL.managerid, 
                CHIL.email, 
                level + 1 
         FROM   TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY CHIL 
                JOIN CTE PARENT 
                  ON CHIL.[managerid] = PARENT.[employeeid]), 
     ANOTHERCTE 
     AS (SELECT   
        T.[email], 
        T.[destination_account], 
        T.[customer_service_rep_code] 
         FROM   [KGFGJK].[DBO].[TRANS] AS T) 
SELECT * 
FROM   ANOTHERCTE 
       INNER JOIN CTE 
               ON CTE.empemail = ANOTHERCTE.[email];
```

Comment: Error is pretty explicit here. What about the error don't you understand and we can try to elaborate.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: @jarlh, I have modified my original question with the data expected result.

Answer (score 1):

A comparison like `=, !=, <>, <, <= , >, >=` only expects 1 value to compare.
So a result with multiple records would cause an error.

But one could use an `EXISTS` for this.

```
...
WHERE A.ManagerEmail = 'user1@abc.com'
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM TOrganization_Hierarchy B
  WHERE B.ManagerEmail = A.ManagerEmail
    AND B.Level <= A.Level
)
```

Btw, looking at the data, it might be more efficient to match with the same ManagerID.

```
...
WHERE A.ManagerEmail = 'user1@abc.com'
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM TOrganization_Hierarchy B
  WHERE B.ManagerID = A.ManagerID
    AND B.Level <= A.Level
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want the level of the manager.  That requires the correct correlation clause:

```
select oh.*
from TOrganization_Hierarchy oh
where oh.ManagerEmail = 'user1@abc.com' and
      oh.Level >= (select oh2.Level
                   from TOrganization_Hierarchy oh2
                   where oh2.Email = oh.ManagerEmail
                  ) ;
```

Notice that I also changed the table aliases, so they are meaningful.

Note that if you want the highest level for a given manager, you can use `max()`:

```
select oh.*
from TOrganization_Hierarchy oh
where oh.ManagerEmail = 'user1@abc.com' and
      oh.Level = (select max(oh2.Level)
                  from TOrganization_Hierarchy oh2
                  where oh2.ManagerEmailEmail = oh.ManagerEmail
                 ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff.  May be my question is not clear but as user1@abc.com I want to see all the records that people reporting to me directly and records of those that report to people under me directly.  Base on the data I want to see EmployeeID 273, 16, 274, 285, 286, 275, 276, 23.  I hope my question is much clear now.